# Por qué un script de Javascript me congela el ordenador?

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy empezando a aprender a programar siguiendo un curso, y me he topado con un problema: al incluir el script de mi archivo de js en el index.html, entra en un bucle infinito de cargar la página en el navegador, y al momento se me congela el ordenador completamente, pero si quito el script todo funciona correctamente, y como estoy aún en proceso de aprender, no sé cómo solucionarlo, ya que para el proyecto que estoy siguiendo necesito el archivo de js.

Un saludo y gracias por vuestra atención! (Adjunto más abajo el código de js hasta ahora)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    iniciarApp();
});

function iniciarApp(){
    crearGaleria();
}

function crearGaleria(){
    const galeria = document.querySelector('.galeria-imagenes');

    for(let i = 1; 1 <= 12; i++){
        const imagen = document.createElement('picture');
         imagen.innerHTML = `
         <source srcset="build/img/imagen_vocalista.avif" 
          type="image/avif">
         <source srcset="build/img/imagen_vocalista.webp" 
          type="image/webp">
         <img loading="lazy" width="200" height="300" 
          src="build/img/imagen_vocalista.jpg" alt="Imagen 
           Vocalista">
        `;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Es difícil saberlo si no muestras un [repro] de tu problema. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Por favor agrega el código de tu archivo Js a la pregunta, puedes hacer click en [edit] para modificar tu pregunta y agregar el código. Seguramente hay un problema en el script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

en tu ciclo for: estas realizando la comparación de 1<=12, esto siempre se cumplirá por lo que tu ciclo será infinito, lo correcto sería i <= 12 ya que es tu contador.

Comment: Sólo para añadir que, como está en un bucle infinito, el hilo que lo ejecuta detiene la ejecución de JS para la página así como está.

Comment: Efectivamente, no me di cuenta de que era la "i" en vez del 1, muchas gracias de verdad!

Comment: Aunque la respuesta es correcta, en estos casos, donde es un error de tipeo, se cierra la pregunta por dicho motivo

Answer (score 2):

Debes cambiar la línea

```
for(let i = 1; 1 <= 12; i++)
```

por

```
for(let i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
```

De esta manera tu ciclo no queda infinito.